# Node.js conflict in dependency resolving

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

- I have created a node module on version `1.0.0`
- I Published it
- Now, in other test project I try to use this dependency, works great
- Then I update the module to version `1.0.1` and install globally but not published it
- So then I tried update the version of dependency on the project test to `1.0.1` but the dependency don't resolves

Do dependencies only resolve from remote server?

Module project:

```
{
  "name": "my-module",
  "version": "1.0.1",
...
}
```

Installing on local repository:

```
npm install --save
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name" : "my-project-test",
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "dependencies" : {
    "my-module": "1.0.1"
  }
  ...
}
```

Resulting error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5

npm ERR! No compatible version found: my-module@1.0.1
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["1.0.0"]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! ./npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You now have multiple installations of your dependency:

1. *Global*, which you have installed using `npm i -g <name>` this is version `1.0.1`.
2. *Local*, thisch was installed previously on version `1.0.0`.

The order by which Node.js tries to locate a module referred by name is as follows:

1. Check to see if the given module is a core module.
2. Search for a directory named `node_modules` in the current directory (project directory).
3. Work the way up the folder hierarchy, checking each level for a `node_modules` folder.
4. Look at the directory paths outlined in the `require.paths` array in node.

Your global `node_modules` directory is in the 4th list item; long after the local `node_modules` directory. Meaning your program stops at the local dependency installed.

Node identified that version `1.0.0` is installed locally, and indicates that in the error. Note the block containing `No compatible version found: my-module@1.0.1`. this is because of your `package.json` having `1.0.1`. Once Node has found the older version, the lookup won't continue, so either upgrade the local installation, or remove it from Node's way.

In order to remove it, use `npm uninstall <name>` in your project directory in order to remove the dependency on version `1.0.0` from Node's way, forcing it to look up the global directory.

*Sources (a VERY recommended read!):*

- Ben Nadel: [Where Does Node.js And Require() Look For Modules?](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)